# WP REST API Custom Endpoint to update ACF in Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

Im setting up an endpoint that I want to use to update ACF fields in a custom post type.

Here I register the field endpoint and callback

```
function wp_api_assign_external_writer() {
  register_rest_route( 'responsify/v1', 'assign_external_writer/', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'assign_external_writer_callback',
    ));
}
function assign_external_writer_callback( $request ) {


$parameters = $request->get_params();
$project_id = $parameters['project_id'];
$writer = $parameters['writer'];

update_field('content_external_writer',$writer,$project_id);

  
}
```

sending this request in postman:
http://localhost:32851/wp-json/responsify/v1/assign_external_writer?writer=32272&project=2527

If I use "title=my_new_title" instead of writer it updates correctly. But using an ACF doesnt update. I read that this should work with `update_field` but it is not. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the variable `$project_id` defined, but then in your update_field() call you are using a different variable name: `$project`

```
update_field('content_external_writer', $writer, $project);
```

If you change your `update_field()` call to use `$project_id` for the $post_id parameter, the update should work:

```
update_field('content_external_writer', $writer, $project_id);
```

Comment: thanks but that was just a typo on my part, I was using the correct post param

Answer (score 0):

I notice using `get_post_meta` that a non-nested key for the metafield exists -       'project_type_content_content_external_writer'

so using

seems to work just fine